# I'm trying to make an unban command but this error shows up. "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Tags: discord.py, python-3.8

### I've tried to fix it but still nothing. Im 100% sure that the problem is with the unban file. Because As soon As I delete the embed the bot works perfectly fine so yeah let me just show the code...

Main File:

```
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
      client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run(My current key)
```

---

Cog Unban file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class unban(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, *, member):
        banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

        for ban_entry in banned_users:
            user = ban_entry.user
        
            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                await ctx.guild.unban(user)
                unban = discord.Embed(title='UnBan Hammer Has Spoken! :boom:', description=f'**Moderator:** {ctx.author}\n **User UnBanned:** {member}, color=0xbd2929)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=unban)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(unban(client))
```

---

Comment: Are you using different editors on the same files or maybe did you copy some snippets from internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your lines in the cog file is missing a `'`, this should fix it:

```
unban = discord.Embed(title='UnBan Hammer Has Spoken! :boom:', description=f'**Moderator:** {ctx.author}\n **User UnBanned:** {member}', color=0xbd2929)
```

Comment: Thank u so much!